# Switch value of a variable in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to do something like that in *SASS*:

```
$GREEN: #57da99;
$HEADER_PURPLE: #8585ff;
$BLUEISH: #4478ff;
$RED: #ff475d;
$RED2: #ff445e;

$currentColor:null;

body.page-about       { $currentColor: $BLUEISH; }
body.page-browse      { $currentColor: $GREEN; }
body.page-signup      { $currentColor: $HEADER_PURPLE; }
body.page-login       { $currentColor: $HEADER_PURPLE; }
body.page-contribute  { $currentColor: $RED; }
```

I've no error,  it's compiled with success. But when I check my page, the value of **$currentColor** is **$RED** even if I'm not in **body.page-contribute**.

So, I don't know if *SASS* doesn't handle it or if I made a big mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, for the record.
It's not possible, because in each line a *new* $currentColor is created in different scopes :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a Sass variable with a global scope, so each line is modifying the global var, like in JavaScript.
You can use `@debug $currentColor;` between you lines to see variable state.

You should probably use a mixin to prevent scope issue, or declare another variable with a local scope each time (try to just delete `$currentColor:null;`)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `$currentColor:null;` - there is no need to instantiate variables in SASS outside their required scope.

```
$GREEN: #57da99;
$HEADER_PURPLE: #8585ff;
$BLUEISH: #4478ff;
$RED: #ff475d;
$RED2: #ff445e;

body.page-about       { $currentColor: $BLUEISH; }
body.page-browse      { $currentColor: $GREEN; }
body.page-signup      { $currentColor: $HEADER_PURPLE; }
body.page-login       { $currentColor: $HEADER_PURPLE; }
body.page-contribute  { $currentColor: $RED; }
```